# How to insert value in Oracle DB with right syntax

Tags: java, oracle

I wrote a query

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5) " +
      "VALUES('" + VAR1+ "','" + VAR2 + "','" + VAR3 + "','" + " '" + VAR4 + "','" + "VAR5 + );";
```

where `var5` is a string.

When I try to insert into table and use above SQL I get the error

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917 : no comma

Where is the mistake?

Comment: `How to insert value in Oracle DB with right syntax` - use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single and double quotes around `VAR5` was not correct and also you don't need `;` in the string:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5) " +
      "VALUES('" + VAR1+ "','" + VAR2 + "','" + VAR3 + "','" + " '" + VAR4 + "','" + VAR5 + "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You had the quotes wrong:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5) " +
      "VALUES('" + VAR1 + "','" + VAR2 + "','" + VAR3 + "','" + VAR4 + "','" + VAR5 + ");";
```

The quote next to last must be placed between the plus and the parenthesis, not before VAR5. Also you doubled the single quote before VAR4 (credit to DevilsHnd).

Comment: Well there is that and there are also two single quote marks (**'**) before `' 'VAR4'`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help

The right syntax is:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5) " +
      " VALUES('" + VAR1+ "','" + VAR2+ "','" + VAR3+ "','" + VAR4+ "','" + VAR5+ "')";
```